# How to adjust the font size based on the content (which is a number and string) in a container?

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, react-redux, font-size

I am having a container which takes in the amount and the currency. As the amount gets bigger and reaches near to the right padding (i.e., 16px), the font size should be reducing. At the same time the top padding of the currency should also change.

https://jsfiddle.net/jmjjeena/uzsL7n0c/

```
//////////////// REACT /////////////////

class FontSize extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
          <div className='subContainer'>
            <div className='amount'>$1000000000.00</div>
          <div className='currency'>USD</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FontSize />, document.querySelector("#app"))

//////////////// CSS /////////////////

body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.container {
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 316px;
  height: 81px;
}

.subContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 16px 16px 12px 28px;
}

.amount {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: black;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.currency {
   padding-top: 17px;
   font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099198/make-html-input-font-size-shrink-as-more-type-is-typed this question may be relevant/help you out

Comment: You'll need a custom function to set font-size based on string length. Here is a quick and dirty example based on your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/onfgpadv/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can make the css dynamics, e.g. something like this:

```
<div style={fontStyle(1)} />


fontStyle= function(fontSze) {
   return {
     font-size:fontSze
   }
 }
```

You will need to add the logic based on the amount changing.  You can update the variable via props and put the logic to update it within the componentDidMount()